# toString,hashcode and equals method inside interface

Tags: java, interface, tostring, hashcode

Below example runs without any errors, can any one explain me how this works?, as interface doesn't contain any toString()/hashcode/equals method declaration how compiler will resolve method call?,as per my understanding toString()/hashcode/equals or Object class methods will be declared by default inside interface? please correct me if am wrong

interface int1
    {
        public void show();
    }

```
class inttest implements int1
{

    public void show() 
    {
        System.out.println("inttest.show()");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "tostring called";
    }
}

public class MainClass1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int1 i=new inttest();
        System.out.println(i.toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Any interface has all the public methods of the `Object` class (it either inherits them from a super-interface or declares them implicitly if it doesn't already declare them explicitly).

This makes sense, since any implementing class of any interface must be a (direct or in-direct) sub-class of the `Object` class, and therefore will inherit an implementation of all the `Object` methods.

> [9.2. Interface Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2)
>
> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless an abstract method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

As all objects extend `Object` and `Object` has a `toString()` you are calling that method.